# Delete all except those specified

Tags: php, mysql

I have a program that sends an entry to my php script which is then added to the database and is updated instead if it already exists

The program sends around 3000 entries and the php script saves the ids into a text file, after all the entries were sent the php script should delete all of the entries from the database except those with ids which are in the text file.

Currently this is my code:

```
if($finished == "yes")
{
  if(file_exists("completed.txt"))
  {
    $completed = file("completed.txt");
    unlink("completed.txt");
    $product = database::query("select * from " . DB_TABLE_PRODUCTS . ";");
    while($row = database::fetch($product))
    {
      if(!in_array($row["ewe"], $completed))
      {
        if($row["ewe"] != "" && $row["ewe"] != null)
        {
          database::query("delete from " . DB_TABLE_PRODUCTS . " where id = '" . $row["id"] . "';");
          database::query("delete from " . DB_TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES . " where product_id = '" . $row["id"] . "';");
          database::query("delete from " . DB_TABLE_PRODUCTS_INFO . " where product_id = '" . $row["id"] . "';");
          database::query("delete from " . DB_TABLE_PRODUCTS_PRICES . " where product_id = '" . $row["id"] . "';");
          $product_images = database::query("select * from " . DB_TABLE_PRODUCTS_IMAGES . " where product_id = '" . $row["id"] . "';");
          while($product_image = database::fetch($product_images))
          {
            if(is_file(FS_DIR_HTTP_ROOT . WS_DIR_IMAGES . $product_image['filename']))
            {
              unlink(FS_DIR_HTTP_ROOT . WS_DIR_IMAGES . $product_image['filename']);
            }
            functions::image_delete_cache(FS_DIR_HTTP_ROOT . WS_DIR_IMAGES . $product_image['filename']);
            database::query("delete from " . DB_TABLE_PRODUCTS_IMAGES . " where product_id = '" . $row["id"] . "' and id = '" . (int)$product_image['id'] . "' limit 1;");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  exit();
}
```

But what happens with above is that all the records from the database get deleted 
and in my case, simply using DELETE FROM x WHERE x NOT IN is not good.

To sum it up i have a program that i run daily which sends about 3000 entries to my php script, which then adds/updates into the database and deleted those records from the database which are not present in the last batch of 3000 records.

Anyone knows how can I do this?

Edit:

I found the culprit, it seems like in_array($row["ewe"], $completed) isn't working corrently, it's returning false even tho it should return true.

I manually checked $row["ewe"] and it was present in both the array and in the database, yet in_array returned false..

Edit 2:

Found the solution, seems like i had spaces/new lines in my array, i solved the problem by using: $completed = array_map("trim", file("completed.txt")); and now it's working like a charm :)

Comment: looks like an ideal candidate for a correctly setup collection of foreign keys with cascade set for delete especially - there are a lot of queries which could be eliminated entirely. As the queries stand you might be better to use the `IN` operator ie: `where id in (2,5,34,44... etc )` which would also require far fewer queries

Comment: but that wouldn't work for me since i'm deleting entries related to the first one from other tables which have different ids

Comment: Can you explain why exactly `DELETE FROM (...) WHERE NOT IN` is "not good"?

Comment: table 1 looks like: ( id, name, ewe ) , other table looks like: ( id, product_id ), here other table product_id is linked to table 1 id, but i work with the EWE field which is kind of an EAN

my php script saves a list of EWE fields, then it deletes by the EWE field but related entries are stored in other tables by the ID field, which i can't know if i do NOT IN

sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

Look into database relationships and constraints: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

In short, you can define that record A (e.g. OBJECT_DETAIL) cannot exist without the master record B (e.g. OBJECT). Then deleting the master all details will also be removed. This is how you ensure database integrity.

To intersect, union, or subtract records between batches, assign each batch a unique identifier.